# Symfony OneToMany with associative array : new row inserted instead of update

Tags: symfony, doctrine, one-to-many

I have to internationalize an app and particularly an entity called Program. To do so, I created an other entity ProgramIntl which contains a "locale" attribute (en_GB, fr_FR, etc) and strings which must be internationalized. I want the programIntl attribute in Program to be an associative array (with locale as key).

We have an API to read/write programs. GET and POST works fine but when I want to update data (PUT), the programIntl is not updated: an insert query is launched (and fails because of the unique constraint, but that's not the question).

Here is the code:

In Program.php:

```
 /**
 * @var
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ProgramIntl", mappedBy="program", cascade={"persist", "remove", "merge"}, indexBy="locale", fetch="EAGER")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false, onDelete="cascade")
 * @Groups({"program_read", "program_write"})
 */
private $programIntl;

public function addProgramIntl($programIntl)
{
    $this->programIntl[$programIntl->getLocale()] = $programIntl;
    $programIntl->setProgram($this);

    return $this;
}

public function setProgramIntl($programIntls)
{
    $this->programIntl->clear();
    foreach ($programIntls as $locale => $programIntl) {
        $programIntl->setLocale($locale);
        $this->addProgramIntl($programIntl);
    }
}

public function getProgramIntl()
{
    return $this->programIntl;
}
```

In ProgramIntl.php:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\ProgramIntlRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="program_intl",uniqueConstraints={@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="program_intl_unique", columns={"program_id", "locale"})})
 */
class ProgramIntl
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @Groups({"program_read", "program_write"})
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Program", inversedBy="programIntl")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $program;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=5, options={"fixed" = true})
     */
    private $locale;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=64)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Groups({"program_read", "program_write"})
     */
    private $some_attr;

    /* ... */
}
```

Any idea of what could be the reason of the "insert" instead of "update" ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to mention that we use api-platform.
But I found the solution myself. In case anyone is interested, adding the following annotation to classes Program and ProgramIntl solved the problem:
/* @ApiResource(attributes={
 *     "normalization_context"={"groups"={"program_read", "program_write"}},
 *     "denormalization_context"={"groups"={"program_read", "program_write"}}
 * }) */